# Perforce add's 'depot' folder when creating a workspace

Tags: perforce

I have a depot structure as following:

```
-> depot
---> artSource
---> Game
```

Until I was changed to an admin account, When connecting a workspace I would only the `ArtSoruce, Game` in my workspace, but since the change, I'm getting the `depot` as well.

All other user's don't have the depot folder, doing the same steps. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Your client view is different from theirs.

A client view of:

```
//depot/... //your-client/...
```

will map `//depot/...` directly to your client root.

A client view of:

```
//depot/... //your-client/depot/...
```

will map `//depot/...` to a folder called `depot` under your client root (as you're describing).

To remove the extra client folder from your workspace, remove it from the view and then `p4 sync` to sync the workspace using the new view.

Note that the former (without the extra folder on the client side) is the default when there is only one depot, but when there are multiple depots, the default view maps each depot to a folder of the same name.  My guess is that your workspace has the extra folder level because there's a second depot that was created since your previous workspace was, or perhaps because there's a second depot that only you (as an admin) have access to.

Comment: I went into the Admin UI and I see `spec, unload` next to the `depot`. I've realized that other user's don't see `spec` as they are not an admin. However even though I exclude `spec` I still get depot.

Comment: Please reread my answer carefully.  You need to change the `View` mapping line that maps `depot`.  (You might not be able to do this through the admin UI -- the command line is easier!  Just run `p4 client` and remove the extra `depot`.)